# Non-sequential list in R-markdown

Tags: html, r-markdown

(R-)Markdown helpfully rendered mis-numbered lists into sequential order, e.g.:

```
1. A
2. B
2. C
```

renders as

1. A
2. B
3. C

I want to write a non-sequential list (specifically reverse-sequence), e.g.

```
3. A
2. B
1. C
```

Which renders as

1. A
2. B
3. C

What I want is it to render in the order it is written.

I've tried escapes `\`, `\\` and extensive googling and have no further idea how to make this happen.

Go on. Eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ol reversed` HTML syntax to reverse the order of your list in r-markdown like this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Quinten"
date: "2024-01-30"
output: html_document
---

<ol reversed>
  <li>A </li>
  <li>B </li>
  <li>C </li>
</ol>
```

Output (I can't upload the output on Stack Overflow right now):

Comment: This does achieve mostly the desired outcome for me, BUT or some reason it renders in a sans serif font when specifying with HTML, while just using a standard markdown list renders in serif, per the rest of the page - which might be due to the qarto theme I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Another (somewhat unsatisfactory) answer is to escape each item in the list, which keeps the numbering, but loses the nice listing formatting of an indent and spacing:

```
3\. A
2\. B
1\. C
```

renders to

3. A
2. B
1. C

(compare format to unescaped, per question)

3. A
4. B
5. C